# Connecting to AWS with Cyberduck/FileZilla/PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, filezilla, cyberduck

I want to change something in a website which uses AWS (Amazon Web Service).

I have to fill the host, username and password.

1. To host field should I enter the elastic IP?
2. Also where can I find what should I write to username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the IP address to the "hostname" field.

The username varies with system you have on your instance. It can be `ec2-user` (RHEL5, Fedora), `ubuntu`, `fedora` or `root` (SUSE).

Password authentication is typically disabled. You have to use a private key.

For details see:

- [Amazon EC2 Key Pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)
- *My guide* to [Connecting Securely to Amazon EC2 Server with SFTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2)

Answer (score 0):

The host name would be your IP address or domain of the site.

The user name would depend on your server. If it's an Ubuntu server, it would be "ubuntu". If it's Amazon Linux, it would be "ec2-user".

Assuming you have a private key, you would have to add the key to the FTP client and connect via SFTP.